# Flutter create command was unsuccessful

Tags: android-studio, flutter

I'm creating a new flutter project in Android studio for the first time. I give the project a name and choose Flutter sdk. I then clicked finish and then noting happened. Android studio says that
"Flutter create command was unsuccessful"
When I navigate to command directory using file explorer, I new folder is created with the project name I've given but it is empty.
Please help.

Comment: Does it work if you use `flutter create your_project_name`? What Flutter version are you using on what OS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you installed flutter correctly. First and foremost, make sure you run **flutter doctor** from your terminal.

If it doesn't work then you didn't install flutter properly.

If it works, try creating your project via terminal by typing **flutter create projectname**

Comment: thanks that's true flutter wasn't installed correctly>

Comment: Glad I could help

Answer (score 1):

I hade the same issue in ubuntu
first, check flutter doctor and solve the error if there was
then check the git installation
in my case, I didn't install git

Answer (score 0):

On Windows at least you need to add `<flutter_dir>\bin` to your path, and then restart Android Studio. It is not clear to me why Android Studio needs to know the location of the Flutter SDK if it doesn't then use that information but... :shrug:

Git also needs to be in the PATH too (as `C:\Program Files\Git\cmd`); I have always used git-bash just fine without that but now it seems to be a requirement that isn't clearly surfaced when upgrading.

Answer (score 0):

In My case set the flutter sdk path first while create the app and then create the app